# How to make an Custom API root list based on permissions

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I wold like to personalize the api_root list based on the current user permissions, so that not all endpoints are visible to all level users.

Ex.:

```
router.register(r'users',views.UserViewSet, base_name='users')
router.register(r'groups', views.GroupViewSet, base_name='groups')
router.register(r'schedules', views.CallSchedulesViewSet, base_name='schedules')
urlpatterns = [  
  url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
  ...
]
```

For "**superuser**" the list should be:

- users
- groups
- schedules

But for "**normaluser**" the list should only be:

- schedules

Answer (score 0):

The routes are registered during application starts. This does not happen on each call. So what you want may not be possible.

One things you can do is to return `404 error not found` instead on `403 unauthorized error/access dened` for the urls user don't have access. From user point of view that is as good as routes don't exist.

Comment: Thanks Arun. What I have done is added a view with no data, it basically does what you mention above.  urlpatterns = [url(r'^$', views.APIRoot.as_view()), url(r'', include(router.urls)),]

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this using the following approach, maybe not the most elegant, but it serves as an example.

**urls.py**

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'users', views.UserViewSet, base_name='users')
router.register(r'groups', views.GroupViewSet, base_name='groups')
router.register(r'schedules', views.SchedulesViewSet, base_name='schedules')

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.APIRoot.as_view()),
    url(r'', include(router.urls)),
    ...
]
```

**views.py**

```
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response

class APIRoot(APIView):
    """
    API Root ...
    """
    def get(self, request):
        data = {
            "users": "http://localhost:8000/users/",
            "groups": "http://localhost:8000/groups/",
            "schedules": "http://localhost:8000/schedules/",
        }

        if not request.user.is_superuser:
            data.pop("users")
            data.pop("groups")

        return Response(data)
```